# Write public ip to txt and upload to FTP automatically? (linux)

Tags: linux, ftp, automation, ip, sh

So I am looking for a way to upload a created Text File of sorts to a ftp

1. It needs to happen every lets say 4 hours

   - check ip
   - write ip to document or whatever
   - upload it to a FTP server with a spesific ipaddress, username and password
2. I am using Linux so a sh script will be fine
3. If you could explain what things go that'd be great
   -(im still learning alot of stuff although being 5 years into use of Linux Mint and Fedora 21)

So far I have

```
dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
```

This gets my public ip and next is to write it to a document and upload it to a ftp server which I do not know.

Just a final additional note, I'm looking for this to run every 4 hours by its self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty first stab:

```
#!/bin/bash
# ftpmyip.sh
HOST=ftpserver
USER=userid
PASSWD=userpw
# write my ip address to file my_ip.txt
dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com > my_ip.txt
# ftp file to the ftp server
ftp -n $HOST <<SCRIPT
user $USER $PASSWD
binary
put my_ip.txt
quit
SCRIPT
```

Now, put it all in a cron job using crontab -e; line should say:

```
0 */4 * * * /home/enviousdata/ftpmyip.sh
```